# Is there a way to delete multiple roles at one go or the whole Role Hierarchy? (with or without inactive users)

Tags: role-hierarchy, roles

Right now I have to delete 1 by 1 and that is really time consuming.

Comment: Curious how you solved for this...or are you still deleting them one at a time!  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user is assigned to a role or if a role has a child role then that role cannot be deleted.

From Salesforce UI, only role at the bottom level can be deleted.

Secondly, when you try to move user from one role to other, try shifting user from the lowest level of the role hierarchy, so that sharing calculation won't take much time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SOQL to find the role (UserRole) records and then delete them just like any other records, but doing so would scare the heck out of me!  ;)

Take a look at slides 16 -- 18 here before you go that route. They'll step you through some other considerations:

https://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/df121283-patterson

...and if you do try it, BE SURE to do so in a sandbox first!!

Comment: System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00E28000001NA2KEAW; first error: DELETE_FAILED, Your attempt to delete the role CEO could not be completed because users are currently assigned to that role or at least one role reports to that role. Yeah probably not possible with active users.

Comment: Ah -- there are still users assigned.  FYI, you can't do it with inactive users still assigned to those roles either.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's late, but here is the solution :

Open dataloader

Be sure the 'Insert null value' setting is activ

Open export and select "Show all salesforce object"

Select the User object

Export all your users with the export feature (you only need the user
ID field and the UserRoleId field)

Open your extract file, Delete all the UserRole Id and save

Open update from your dataloader

Select The user object

Use your file and map the UserID and the UserIdRole and next :P

There you go, the dataloader will modify all your user by deleting the previous value in the UserRoleId field ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is not about removing the user role field in bulk, but rather removing the role completely as an object. Meaning the role won't be selectable in the user detail.

Comment: Well, to do that, you already need to ensure that your users are not assigned to this role.

If you got hundreds of user assigned to a specific role, you will need my method to remove the role field in bulk.

Then, if you are sure that any users are assigned to a role you want to delete, you just need to extract your UserRoleId from the same object with your dataloader.
And to finish, you delete the role with your dataloader ;)

Comment: Yes that is true, but ultimately it is not an answer to the question above.